# Как перейти с webView на activity

Tags: android, activity, webview

у меня есть форма входа в webViewи мне нужно сделать так, чтобы при вводе правильных данных приложение направляло пользователя на другое активити
вот код

```
$(function() {
  $('.submit').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault(); // предотвращаем распространение события по умолчанию
    var inp1 = $('#inp1').val();
    var inp2 = $('#inp2').val();
    var url = "тут должно быть перенаправление на активити";
    if (inp1 == 'exmp@mail.ru' && inp2 == 'exp111') {
      document.location.href =  url;
    } else {
      $('.err').html('Данные введены неправильно!');
    }
  });
});

<div class="log_in">
    <p class="err"></p>
    <input id="inp1" type="email" name="name" placeholder="почта" required><br>
    <input id="inp2"  type="password" name="pass" placeholder="пароль" required><br><br><br>
    <a  class="submit"  href="">Вход</a>
```

```
webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Нужно добавить примерно следующее:

```
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient()
{
    // Используем этот метод для версий API ниже 24:
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url)
    {
        final Uri uri = Uri.parse(url);
        return shouldOverrideUrlLoading(uri);
    }

    // Используем этот метод для версий API 24 и выше: 
    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request)
    {
        final Uri uri = request.getUrl();
        return shouldOverrideUrlLoading(uri);
    }

    private boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(final Uri uri)
    {
        if (isActivityUrl(url))
        {
            // Создаем Activity: 
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, Activity.class); // Тут Activity нужно заменить на нужный класс.
            startActivity(intent);
            //
            // Возврат true означает, что мы обрабатываем переход самостоятельно:
            return true;
        }
        //
        // Возврат false означает, что мы оставляем обработку события перехода WebView:
        return false;
    }

    private boolean isActivityUrl(final Uri uri)
    {
        // Проверяем, тот ли это url:
        // <...>
    }
});
```

Метод `shouldOverrideUrlLoading(...)` будет вызываться каждый раз, когда внутри `WebView` происходит переход по ссылке.

Ресурсы:

[Запуск новой Activity](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html)

[WebViewClient и метод `shouldOverrideUrlLoading(...)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html#shouldOverrideUrlLoading(android.webkit.WebView,%20android.webkit.WebResourceRequest))

Comment: а что нужно написать на месте ссылки? и что нужно вставить на место //совершаем требуемое действие, скрипт, который я показал, написан в файле  index.html в папке asset

Comment: Требуемое действие – непосредственно создания нужной Activity. На месте ссылки – любая ссылка, в общем-то. Например, http://{название_приложения}/{название_activity}. Дальше в `isActivityUrl(...)` добавляем проверку, нужная ли это ссылка. Грубо говоря: `return url == "http://{название_приложения}/{название_activity}";`

Comment: а как организовать действие создание нужной Activity?

Comment: Изменила ответ.

Comment: все получилось, только теперь новое активити появляется при клике по любой ссылке, а нужно только по определенной. Как исправить это?

Comment: я понял что проблема в том, что url находится в другом файле(index.html ), а весь код в Activity. Мне как-то нужно обратиться к этой переменной js находящейся  в файле index.html. Подскажите пожалуйста как это сделать

Comment: Как сейчас выглядит метод `isActivityUrl(...)`?

Comment: return url == "href://Pain_S/ActivityTwo";

Answer (score 1):

А можно подключить свой интерфейс:

```
webView.addJavascriptInterface(new JSMy(this), "my");
```

И класс:

```
public class JS {
    private Context context;

    public JS(Context context) {
       this.context = context;
    }

    public boolean openActivity(String activityName) {
        try {
            Class<?> clazz = Class.forName(activityName);
            Intent intent = new Intent(context, clazz);
            context.startActivity(intent);
            return true;
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

И дальше вызывать метод `my.openActivity("AuthActivity")` уже через js:

```
var inp2 = $('#inp2').val();
var url = "тут должно быть перенаправление на активити";
if (inp1 == 'exmp@mail.ru' && inp2 == 'exp111') {
    my.openActivity("AuthActivity");
}
```

Comment: почему-то когда я вызываю метод, он не обнаруживается

Comment: Попробуйте добавить аннотацию к методу @JavascriptInterface

Comment: а мне этот ответ кажется более верным, странно что его не апают. Ведь действительно WebView поддерживает совместимость JS до Java и наоборот почему этим не пользоваться ? В свой время писал огромную игру, используя JSInterface. Всё отлично работает до сих пор. Там кстати нужно закастить для клиента поддержку JavaScript явно иначе не будет работать